# MySQL SUM query problems php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have the following query running in PHP:

```
$ticketTotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`tickets_issued`) FROM `tb_att_registered_attendants` WHERE `confirmation_code`!='000000'");
```

But when I return `$ticketTotal`, I get `Resource id #33` and when I dump the variable, I get `resource(33) of type (mysql result)`. When I run the exact same query in phpMyAdmin, I get the correct result. I can't seem to find much on google. What is going on?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ticketTotal` doesn't hold your query results. You still have to actually fetch them.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketTotal))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: So is there an easier way to update an old application that has around 5k queries running across about 200 different files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using PHP5.5.0, then you can use below way, since mysql_result is deprecreated as of PHP5.5.0

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`tickets_issued`) FROM `tb_att_registered_attendants` WHERE `confirmation_code`!='000000'");
$ticketTotal = mysql_result($result,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
$Row = mysql_fetch_array($ticketTotal);
$sum = $Row['SUM(tickets_issued)'];
```

I have tested it for my code and it works properly.